# How to copy string without allocating memory - C

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy

I just started in C and this is a beginner question. But is there any way to copy a string without allocating memory beforehand?
I want to reproduce the strcopy function inbuilt in C with the same structure (`char *strcpy(char *src, char *dest);`). I got it to work with declaring the char pointer in the function itself and then returning it. It works also with the original structure as strcpy if I allocate the memory beforehand.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strcopy(char *src, char *dest)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int str_size(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *src = argv[1];
    char *dest = (char*)malloc(str_size(src));
    dest = strcopy(src, dest);
    return (0);
}
```

So is it somehow possible to copy a string without allocating memory beforehand and without changing my function-head?

Comment: Copy it to what? There has to be some memory location you want to copy to.

Comment: Too short: you need `char *dest = malloc(str_size(src) + 1);` to allow for the terminator. You can use the non-standard `strdup()` but there is still memory allocation inside the function.

Comment: So it is in no way possible to copy the string without allocating memory? Because it worked before with the `char *dest;` declaration in the strcopy function.
@WeatherVane actually I dont need the `... str_size(src) + 1 ...` It worked fine just itself

Comment: Yes you do: you need room for the null terminator `dest[i] = '\0';` Perhaps on some occasions `char *dest` happened to point to available memory, but it is still undefined behaviour. Appearing to be "working just fine" is one possible outcome.

Comment: Oh im sorry, I changed my code, before it was `int i = 1;` Thats why it worked.

Comment: You can have a static char array if you wanna avoid malloc.

Comment: Your question is similar to "Can I put eggs in a basket without having a basket first?"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid dynamic allocation, use static allocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE        1024

char *strcopy(char *src, char *dest)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0')
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

int str_size(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *src = argv[1];
    char dest[BUFFER_SIZE];
    
    if(strlen(src) >= BUFFER_SIZE){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        dest = strcopy(src, dest);
    }

    return 0;
}
```